# HTML5 canvas paint realistic simple pencil

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, brush

How i can create realistic simple pencil tool, not like in a ms windows paint program. I need result like this: [image]

if i try solid without transparent i get like in a ms windows paint programs not realistic pencil, if i try add opacity i see circles this is too not realistic:[image]

How i can get pencil tool like in first picture? my trying example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var previousMouseX = null;
var previousMouse = null;
var isDrawing = false;

var lineWidth = 10;
var brush = 1;
var myColor = "#FF0000";

function getMousePosition(canvas, evt) {
    
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    if (evt.clientX !== undefined && evt.clientY !== undefined) {
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };   
    } 
}

/* BUTTONS */
$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = "0.2";
});

$("#btn2").on("click", function() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = "1";
});

$("#change-color").on("click", function() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#009933";
});

$("#canvas").on("mousedown", function(e) {
    isDrawing = true;
    var pos = getMousePosition(canvas, e);
    move(pos.x, pos.y);

});

$("#canvas").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if(isDrawing) {
        var pos = getMousePosition(canvas, e);
        stroke(pos.x, pos.y);   
    }
});

$("#canvas").on("mouseup", function() {
    isDrawing = false;
});

function stroke(mouseX, mouseY) {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(previousMouseX, previousMouseY);
        ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        move(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function move(mouseX, mouseY) {
        previousMouseX = mouseX;
        previousMouseY = mouseY;
}
```

```css
canvas  {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Transparent">
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Solid">
<input type="button" id="change-color" value="Green color"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this go anywhere near doing what you want?

Draw at pencil using transparent, line width 10 and then draw over the line solid using smaller line width (8). Perhaps you could get more variation by randomly varying the second line width between 7, 8 and 9?

EDIT could also randomly set opacity of second line between say 1 and 0.8!

Permanently set opacity on first line and added this code to the function stroke()

```
    ctx.globalAlpha = "1";
    ctx.lineWidth = 6;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(previousMouseX, previousMouseY);
    ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
```

Changed code snippet

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var previousMouseX = null;
var previousMouse = null;
var isDrawing = false;

var lineWidth = 10;
var brush = 1;
var myColor = "#FF0000";

function getMousePosition(canvas, evt) {
    
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    if (evt.clientX !== undefined && evt.clientY !== undefined) {
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };   
    } 
}

/* BUTTONS */
$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = "0.2";
});

$("#btn2").on("click", function() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = "1";
});

$("#change-color").on("click", function() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#009933";
});

$("#canvas").on("mousedown", function(e) {
    isDrawing = true;
    var pos = getMousePosition(canvas, e);
    move(pos.x, pos.y);

});

$("#canvas").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if(isDrawing) {
        var pos = getMousePosition(canvas, e);
        stroke(pos.x, pos.y);   
    }
});

$("#canvas").on("mouseup", function() {
    isDrawing = false;
});

function stroke(mouseX, mouseY) {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.globalAlpha = "0.2";  //NOTE ALWAYS SET TO 'TRANSPARENT' needs variable if you want to switch to solid.
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(previousMouseX, previousMouseY);
        ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.globalAlpha = "1";
        ctx.lineWidth = 6;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(previousMouseX, previousMouseY);
        ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

        move(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function move(mouseX, mouseY) {
        previousMouseX = mouseX;
        previousMouseY = mouseY;
}
```

```css
canvas  {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Transparent">
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Solid">
<input type="button" id="change-color" value="Green color"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's a pencil effect.

It's adapted from this nice chalk effect done by Mohamed Moustafa: http://codepen.io/mmoustafa/pen/gmEdk

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw,ch;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY,mouseX,mouseY;


var xLast = 0;
var yLast = 0;
var brushDiameter=2;
var fill1='rgba(255,255,255,0.5)';

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/pad.jpg";
function start(){

  cw=canvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=img.height;

  ctx.fillStyle = fill1; 
  ctx.strokeStyle = fill1; 
  ctx.lineWidth = brushDiameter;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  getOffset();
  xLast=mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  yLast=mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  isDown=true;

  draw(mouseX+1, mouseY+1);
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  getOffset();
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  draw(mouseX,mouseY);
}

//252,254,171        
function draw(x,y){
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,'+(0.4+Math.random()*0.2)+')';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(xLast, yLast);  
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();

  // Chalk Effect
  var length = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-xLast,2)+Math.pow(y-yLast,2))/(5/brushDiameter));
  var xUnit = (x-xLast)/length;
  var yUnit = (y-yLast)/length;
  for(var i=0; i<length; i++ ){
    var xCurrent = xLast+(i*xUnit); 
    var yCurrent = yLast+(i*yUnit);
    var xRandom = xCurrent+(Math.random()-0.5)*brushDiameter*1.2;   
    var yRandom = yCurrent+(Math.random()-0.5)*brushDiameter*1.2;
    ctx.clearRect( xRandom, yRandom, Math.random()*2+2, Math.random()+1);
  }
  xLast = x;
  yLast = y; 
}

function getOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; background:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag to draw pencil line on the pad</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: code doesn't appear to run anymore. not obvious why.